# Alternatives ways to check If I click inside or outside a box in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to check if user clicks inside or outside a certain area. In detail I need to know if I click on a `react-select` or on any other component. I found out I could do it in the following way:

```
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.addEventListener('click', function (e: any) {
      const boxId = e.target?.id;
      if (boxId === labelId) {
        //isClicking inside the box
        setIsFocusing(true);
      } else {
        //isClicking outside the box
        setIsFocusing(false);
      }
    });
  }
```

boxId contains the **id** of the component you are clicking on. So this could be the solution.

*My actual problem* is that apparently I can't set an Id to the `react-select` component even if the [official doc](https://react-select.com/props#prop-types) says you can through the classical way, which means giving the id prop to the component.

In [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-meadow-ktle1?file=/src/App.js) I did two examples. One with a **basic select** and one with **react-select**. The basic one works how it is supposed to. I click on a label, the select appears and then you can select. When you click outside then it disappears and visualize the label. Can't do that with react-select because I can't set an ID to it.

Actually can't do it with `onClick` or `onFocus` because I can't check if I click outside.

How do you think I could solve this problem?

Comment: What is the specific use case you are trying to cover? Using a native event listener you can always traverse up the tree to test ancestors of the event target

Comment: instead of showing both at once label and the select next to it, I want to show only the label. If user wants to filter then he clicks on the label and the select appears. User selects one option and then select disappears and show label with the selected option. I want to do this in my project because it's much more beautiful and simple in my opinion. If you take a look at the sandbox the green one (basic select) works how It is supposed to do.

Comment: Seems like it would be fairly simple to just use react events on the label. No need for element IDs that way

Comment: It is actually adding an Id to the select element but the target of the click is the container. The bigger issue is that you're assigning the same Id to multiple elements which isn't valid HTML

Comment: You should probably just use the provided [`onMenuClose`](https://react-select.com/props#api) event

Comment: @charlietfl that would be fine only when I want to open it, not to close it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes... the other event would be on the select

Comment: @pilchard yeah I added same IDs but on the real project they are the different. I remember you that my problem Is to identify whether I click on the select (then don't close it but make the user to select) after selecting or clicking outside then close it.

Comment: @charlietfl I would need events on every component because I want to close it when I click on something different of the select itself

Comment: Not sure why that would be a problem. Don't think of dom elements, think of changing state. Also consider creating a component to wrap the select/label and manage the visibility state within that component

Comment: Here's a quick working example of just using the provided methods. The component already closes on click outside, so you just need to listen for the close event. [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-panna-5cevi?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: @pilchard Thank you! Didn't think at that. Put the answer so I can choose it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating a seperate window level listener, you can leverage the methods/events provided by the component to achieve this.

The [react-select](https://react-select.com/home) component will already close on clicking outside and provides an [`onMenuClose`](https://react-select.com/props#api) event that you listen for and set your state accordingly. I've included a `useEffect` to assign focus to the select when the focus state changes as it won't register the click outside unless focused, but you can find a more elegant solution in the context of your project as need be.

Here's a quick example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-panna-5cevi?file=/src/App.js)

```
export default function App() {
  const [isFocusingReactSelect, setIsFocusingReactSelect] = useState(false);

  const selectRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocusingReactSelect) {
      selectRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, [isFocusingReactSelect]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>show select based on where you click</h2>
      <div style={{ width: "100%", height: 200 }}>
        {!isFocusingReactSelect ? (
          <div
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "gray",
              width: "100%",
              height: 40,
              cursor: "pointer"
            }}
            onClick={() => setIsFocusingReactSelect(true)}
          >
            <p>react-select</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <Select
            ref={selectRef}
            options={options}
            closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            onMenuClose={() => setIsFocusingReactSelect(false)}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```